# Alternate, interweave or interlace two vectors

Tags: r, vector

I want to interlace two vectors of same mode and equal length. Say:

```
a <- rpois(lambda=3,n=5e5)
b <- rpois(lambda=4,n=5e5)
```

I would like to interweave or interlace these two vectors, to create a vector that would be equivalently `c(a[1],b[1],a[2],b[2],...,a[length(a)],b[length(b)])`

My first attempt was this:

```
sapply(X=rep.int(c(3,4),times=5e5),FUN=rpois,n=1)
```

but it requires `rpois` to be called far more times than needed.

My best attempt so far has been to transform it into a matrix and reconvert back into a vector:

```
d <- c(rbind(rpois(lambda=3,n=5e5),rpois(lambda=4,n=5e5)))
d <- c(rbind(a,b))
```

Is there a better way to go about doing it? Or is there a function in base `R` that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `rbind` method should work well.  You could also use

```
rpois(lambda=c(3,4),n=1e6)
```

because R will automatically replicate the vector of lambda values to the required length.  There's not much difference in speed:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(rpois(1e6,c(3,4)),
     c(rbind(rpois(5e5,3),rpois(5e5,4))))


#                                        test replications elapsed relative
# 2 c(rbind(rpois(5e+05, 3), rpois(5e+05, 4)))          100  23.390 1.112168
# 1                      rpois(1e+06, c(3, 4))          100  21.031 1.000000
```

and elegance is in the eye of the beholder ...  of course, the `c(rbind(...))` method works in general for constructing alternating vectors, while the other solution is specific to `rpois` or other functions that replicate their arguments in that way.

Answer (score 4):

Some speed tests, incorporating Ben Bolker's answer:

```
 benchmark(
 c(rbind(rpois(lambda=3,n=5e5),rpois(lambda=4,n=5e5))),
 c(t(sapply(X=list(3,4),FUN=rpois,n=5e5))),
 sapply(X=rep.int(c(3,4),times=5e5),FUN=rpois,n=1),
 rpois(lambda=c(3,4),n=1e6),
 rpois(lambda=rep.int(c(3,4),times=5e5),n=1e6)
 )
                                                                  test
1 c(rbind(rpois(lambda = 3, n = 5e+05), rpois(lambda = 4, n = 5e+05)))
2                 c(t(sapply(X = list(3, 4), FUN = rpois, n = 5e+05)))
4                                   rpois(lambda = c(3, 4), n = 1e+06)
5           rpois(lambda = rep.int(c(3, 4), times = 5e+05), n = 1e+06)
3      sapply(X = rep.int(c(3, 4), times = 5e+05), FUN = rpois, n = 1)
  replications elapsed   relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1          100    6.14   1.000000      5.93     0.15         NA        NA
2          100    7.11   1.157980      7.02     0.02         NA        NA
4          100   14.09   2.294788     13.61     0.05         NA        NA
5          100   14.24   2.319218     13.73     0.21         NA        NA
3          100  700.84 114.143322    683.51     0.50         NA        NA
```

Comment: I'm quite shocked to see just how well the `rbind` command works here. I seem to remember useRs very strongly protesting rbind and cbind as memory gobblers...