# R: how to get elements from a vector into specific positions of a new vector

Tags: r, vector, sequences

I'm using R and I have the following vectors:

```
odd<- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)
even<- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
```

I want to combine even and odd so I can have a vector (let's say it will be named total) with the following elements

```
> total
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...,20.
```

I've tried looping as:

```
total<- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) #20 elements

for (i in seq(from=1, to=20, by=2)) 
  for (j in seq(from=1, to=10, by=1))
     total[i]<- odd[j]


for (i in seq(from=2, to=20, by=2)) 
      for (j in seq(from=1, to=10, by=1))
         total[i]<- even[j]
```

But for some reason this is not working. I'm getting this vector

```
>total
17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 17 20 19 20
```

does anyone no why my looping is not working for this case?

of course, this is only a very simple example of what I have to do with a very large dataset.

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate, interweave or interlace two vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044616/alternate-interweave-or-interlace-two-vectors). You pretty much want `c(rbind(odd,even))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you problem is because you are adding items from odd(and even in the second loops) to the same position in the total using your code line:

```
total[i]<- odd[j]
```

try this instead;

```
odd<- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)
even<- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)

elements = 20
total<- rep(x=0, times=elements) #20 elements

total[seq(from=1, to=length(total), by=2)] = odd
total[seq(from=2, to=length(total), by=2)] = even
total

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

seq creates a sequence of values that I have used here to identify positions to insert the values from odd and even.

Comment: thanks for your note @Scott. I completely missed the possibility of working with sequences in total[]=odd or even, instead of looping twice over my objects!!

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are wrong. As Scott mentioned you insert `odd[j]` into the same position in total for all values of `j`. If you insist on using a `for` loop then if you do it like this you'll get what you want:

```
for (j in seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)) {
    total[2*j-1]<- odd[j]
    total[2*j] <- even[j]
}
```

The methods provided by others don't use loops and are preferable.

Comment: thanks for your example with a loop @Bhas. Yes, I was wrong in doing odd[j].