# Insert value to vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, say `vec = c(1,3,2)`. I want to insert a value, e.g., -1, after each of the value, so that to get `c(1,-1,3,-1,2,-1)`. How to achieve that with some simple function?

Comment: Try: `as.vector(rbind(vec,-1))`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044616/alternate-interweave-or-interlace-two-vectors